# datatable won't update

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I wanted to update my database that contains two text and one filename that is needed for image.

The problem is that the image and filename updates but the two other text values title and body wont be affected and don't change the previous values. Also visual studio don't get any problem and the message for executing command shows that it's executed the command but nothing except the image changes.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (Session["user"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");

        if (Request .QueryString ["action"]=="edit")
        {
            Panel1.Visible = true;
        }

        if (Request.QueryString["edit"] != null)
        {


            Panel1.Visible = true;
            SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection();
            con2.ConnectionString =GNews.Properties.Settings.Default.connectionstring;
            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            con2.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from loadpost_view where Postid=" + Request.QueryString["edit"].ToString () + "", con2);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();



            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                title_txt.Text=myReader ["Title"].ToString ();
                bodytxt.Text = myReader["Body"].ToString();
            }
            con2.Close();
        }
protected void btn_addpost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
string title= title_txt .Text ;
string body=bodytxt .Text ;

if (Request.QueryString["edit"] != null)
{
    string message;

    string filename = thumb_uploader.FileName;
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Thumb";
    string exup = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(thumb_uploader.FileName);
    string[] ext = { ".jpg", ".png", ".jpeg" };
    if (Array.IndexOf(ext, exup) < 0)
    {
        message = "not correct.";
    }

    if (thumb_uploader.FileBytes.Length / 1024 > 400)
    {
        message = "not currect.";
    }

    while (System.IO.File.Exists(path + "\\" + filename + exup))
    {
        filename += "1";
    }

    savepath = path + "\\" + filename;

    if (thumb_uploader.HasFile)
    {
        thumb_uploader.SaveAs(savepath);

        thumb = thumb_uploader.FileName;
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection();

        con3.ConnectionString = GNews.Properties.Settings.Default.connectionstring;
        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = con3;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = command;

        command.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_post SET Title=@title ,Body=@body ,Thumb=@thu Where Postid=" + Request.QueryString["edit"].ToString();
        con3.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title );
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body", body );
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thu", thumb_uploader .FileName);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con3.Close();
        message = "its ok.";
        lbl_result.Text = message;
   }
   else
   {
        using (SqlConnection con3 = new SqlConnection(GNews.Properties.Settings.Default.connectionstring))
        {
            string sql = "update tbl_post SET Title=@title ,Body=@body  Where Postid=@postid" ;
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con3))
            {
                con3.Open();

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body", body);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postid",  Request.QueryString["edit"].ToString());

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con3.Close();
                message = "its ok.";
                lbl_result.Text = message;
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It seems possible that you are missing a check on IsPostback in your Page_Load event. Could you show the code of that event?

Comment: @hamidmosavi just change the string variable name as title1 and body1 and try..its not a apt solution..sometimes it cause problems for me if the parameter name and the variable name are same

Comment: I've tried that but with no help...

Comment: I've found out what caused the update problem, it was the page load event if that I made that the after passing the condition it fills the textboxes with the previous value. Now anyone knows how to solve this problem and what causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer I needed this code to include my pageload reading database so it wouldn't do it when I click on the update button.I mean the problem was all about the post back thing.

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["edit"] != null)
            {


                Panel1.Visible = true;
                SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection();
                con2.ConnectionString = GNews.Properties.Settings.Default.connectionstring;
                DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
                con2.Open();
                SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from loadpost_view where Postid=" + Request.QueryString["edit"].ToString() + "", con2);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();



                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    title_txt.Text = myReader["Title"].ToString();
                    bodytxt.Text = myReader["Body"].ToString();
                }
                con2.Close();
            }
        }
```